# Regex Base64 image with headers

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I'm having an issue with base64 images that are not converting correctly sometimes. I need a way to test if the image is in correct base64 format before converting it so I can try to look further into the problem. I have found some regex formulas online, but I think they only expect the string without the headers. I have the string with the headers. I tried to add the headers, but it keeps breaking.

The original:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$
```

The I added the headers but it doesn't work:

```
^([data:image/png;base64,][A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you look up the regex docs before modifying the regex pattern, or did you just slap that bit on the front and hope for the best? What trouble shooting have you done other than concluding "it doesn't work"? Did you try to work out *why* it doesn't work?

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand the question, but this site has a nice base64 to image converter http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/

Comment: Also, is there any JSON going on.   I recently ran into a serializeJSon() issue with ColdFusion and some base64 images.  See https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3837347 if this is possibly an issue for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may notice in the original regex the use of `[square brackets]`, these create character sets matching any character within so `[data:image/png;base64,]` will match `d,a,t,a,....,6,4,`**`,`**. Instead, you may want to create a *non-capturing group* because I think you're trying to make the header optional, like this `(?:data:image/png;base64,)?`

```
^((?:data:image/png;base64,)?[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$

^                                 # Anchors to the beginning to the string.
(                                 # Opens CG1
 (?:data:image/png;base64,        # Opens NCG1
                                    # Literal data:image/png;base64,
 )?                               # Closes NCG1
                                    # ? repeats zero or one times
 [A-Za-z0-9+/]                    # Character class (any of the characters within)
                                    # Anything between A and Z
                                    # Anything between a and z
                                    # Anything between 0 and 9
                                    # Any of: +/
 {4}                              # Repeats 4 times.
)*                                # Closes CG1
                                    # * repeats zero or more times
(                                 # Opens CG2
 [A-Za-z0-9+/]                    # Character class (any of the characters within)
                                    # Anything between A and Z
                                    # Anything between a and z
                                    # Anything between 0 and 9
                                    # Any of: +/
 {4}                              # Repeats 4 times.
 |                                # Alt (CG2)
 [A-Za-z0-9+/]                    # Character class (any of the characters within)
                                    # Anything between A and Z
                                    # Anything between a and z
                                    # Anything between 0 and 9
                                    # Any of: +/
 {3}                              # Repeats 3 times.
 =                                # Literal =
 |                                # Alt (CG2)
 [A-Za-z0-9+/]                    # Character class (any of the characters within)
                                    # Anything between A and Z
                                    # Anything between a and z
                                    # Anything between 0 and 9
                                    # Any of: +/
 {2}                              # Repeats 2 times.
 ==                               # Literal ==
)                                 # Closes CG2
$                                 # Anchors to the end to the string.
```

If, however, you want to require the headers, you can remove the non-capturing group and the `?` quantifier altogether.

```
^(data:image/png;base64,[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$
```

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression

```
^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$
```

What does all those characters mean:

`^` ... find a string which starts at beginning of a line or string buffer.

`(` ... `)` ... define a marking group for back referencing the string found by the expression inside the parentheses or for applying a multiplier like used here. Grouping an expression just for applying a multiplier is usually better than with a non marking group, i.e. with `(?:` ... `)` where the question mark and the colon immediately after opening parenthesis makes the group a non marking group.

`[` ... `]` ... define a positive class of characters which means that any of the characters within the square brackets should be found once for a positive match. `[^` ... `]` would be a negative character class definition which means any character except one of the characters in the square brackets should be found.

`[A-Za-z0-9+/]` ... a character being either an upper case or a lower case letter from ASCII table or a digit or the plus sign or a slash.

`{4}` ... is a multiplier and means previous expression or character exactly four times.

`*` ... is also a multiplier and means previous expression or character 0 or more times.

`|` ... means **OR**.

`$` ... means end of line without matching line terminator or end of string buffer.

So this expression means:

1. Find a string which starts at beginning of a line or the string buffer,
2. consisting of 0 or more substrings with exactly 4 characters each consisting itself of letters, digits, plus signs, or slash characters,
3. and last substring at end of line or string buffer is either

   - also string consisting of 4 letters, digits, plus signs, or slashes characters,
   - **OR** a string consisting of just 3 letters, digits, plus signs, or slashes and an equal sign as fourth character,
   - **OR** a string consisting of just 2 letters, digits, plus signs, or slashes and two equal signs as third and fourth character.

To allow additionally at beginning of line or string buffer **optionally** a header string, the expression should be modified to:

```
^(?:data:image/png;base64,)?(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$
```

The question mark after the non marking group`(?:data:image/png;base64,)` means here the previous expression (just a fixed string) zero or one times.

As you can see I changed also the 2 marking groups into 2 non marking groups by inserting `?:` after the opening parentheses.